# How to install Transmission or Aria2 for Raspberry Pi 4B OpenWrt

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, openwrt

[image: LEDE Version]

I installed OpenWrt (LEDE) on the Raspberry Pi 4B, the BT download tool is not installed by default.
I use these commands:

```
opkg update
opkg install transmission-daemon-openssl
opkg install aria2
```

But it shows :

```
Unknown package 'transmission-daemon-openssl'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package transmission-daemon-openssl.

Unknown package 'aria2'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package aria2.
```

I used the command `opkg list | grep "transmission"` to view the software list and found that:
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg list |grep "transmission"

```
Package transmission-cli version 3.00-12 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
Package transmission-daemon version 3.00-12 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
Package transmission-remote version 3.00-12 has no valid architecture, ignoring.
```

I confirmed that the configuration in ***/etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf*** uses ***aarch64_generic***，So is there no Transmission or Aria2 for the aarch64?